# Pandas agrupar em grupos com um range determinando

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ciência-de-dados

beleza? Estou tentando agrupar valores de um dataframe que se chama

> df_agenda

por idade, queria agrupar os valores dessa forma na idade: de (0-20),(20-40), (40-60) e assim até o maximo valor da lista de idade.

```
    status_consulta confirm_consulta  idade       sexo  contagem
171        AGENDADA        DESMARCOU      5   FEMININO         1
140        AGENDADA  FALTA_CONFIRMAR      6  MASCULINO         1
47       FINALIZADA       CONFIRMADO      7  MASCULINO         3
131        AGENDADA  FALTA_CONFIRMAR      7   FEMININO         1
217      FINALIZADA       CONFIRMADO      7   FEMININO         1
216      FINALIZADA       CONFIRMADO      8  MASCULINO         1
130        AGENDADA  FALTA_CONFIRMAR      9  MASCULINO         1
34       FINALIZADA       CONFIRMADO      9  MASCULINO         4
139        AGENDADA  FALTA_CONFIRMAR     10   FEMININO         1
77       FINALIZADA       CONFIRMADO     10  MASCULINO         2
129        AGENDADA  FALTA_CONFIRMAR     10  MASCULINO         1
215      FINALIZADA       CONFIRMADO     11  MASCULINO         1
28       FINALIZADA       CONFIRMADO     12  MASCULINO         4
128        AGENDADA  FALTA_CONFIRMAR     12  MASCULINO         1
123        AGENDADA  FALTA_CONFIRMAR     14  MASCULINO         1
193      FINALIZADA       CONFIRMADO     14  MASCULINO         1
```

tentei dessa forma:

```
df_agenda = df_agenda.sort_values(by='idade')
df_agenda = df_agenda.groupby(cut(df_agenda['idade'], np.arange(0, max(n), 20)))
print(df_agenda.head())
```

mas o meu retorno é:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Alguém? Valeu

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro crie uma coluna com a faixa etária (pode ser utilizando o `pd.cut` como você tentou), depois agrupe por ela:

```
df = ... # seu DataFrame aqui
faixas_etarias = np.arange(0, df['idade'].max()+1, 20)
df['faixa_etaria'] = pd.cut(df['idade'], faixas_etarias)

# A partir daqui, use `df.groupby` para agrupar pela coluna 'faixa_etaria'
df_agrupado = df.groupby('faixa_etaria')
```

Note que `df_agrupado` é um objeto do tipo `DataFrameGroupBy`, sobre o qual você normalmente vai querer fazer uma operação que será aplicada a cada grupo. Por exemplo, `df_agrupado['idade'].mean()` mostrará a média de idade dentro de cada grupo de faixa etária.

Comment: Ajudou bastante, obrigado!